# Evaluate hash function

Tags: hash

I am trying to figure out how to evaluate the security of a hash function. If I have defined a candidate hash function: $$H(x) = α^x\text{ mod }p$$ how do I then evaluate it with respect to collision attacks, second preimage attacks, and preimage attacks? Hope someone can help

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography.SE. Does the domain is restricted? What did you try up to now? Can you find $x$ and $y$ such that $a^x = x^y$ easily? Hint: Little Fermat!

Comment: Note that a hash is [a particular kind of](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/8773/8287) one-way function, optimized for computational applications. I assume you're trying to construct and evaluate OWFs in the general case?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because a full description of how to analyze a hash function that is not secure is not needed. Please have a look at the SHA-3 competition to see what you're up against.

Answer (score 1):

If $x=y \mod \phi(p)$, then $H(x)= H(y)$. Then it doesn't seem collision resistant.
For the same reason not second preimage attacks. $H(x + \phi(p))= H(y)$.
(If $p$ is prime $\phi(p)=p-1$, thus it's easy to compute it).

About the preimage attack, it's completely equivalent to discrete logarithm in $\mathbb{Z}^{\star}_p$, then you have to be carrefull about the choice of $p$ (basically $p-1$ should have a huge factor).